# How to search for a whole word, not just a substring with PHP

Tags: php

If I had the following strings: "brasil" and "brasil-carinhoso", I want to replace only "brasil" but not if its directly followed by other characters.

so if I have this list: "pac pac pac brasil brasil-carinhoso pac brasil", if I try to use the following code, it fails:

```
//$_GET['exclusion_tags'] is 'brazil'
//$tags_maior is the string: "pac pac pac brasil brasil-carinhoso pac brasil" 
$tags_maior = preg_replace('/\b'.$_GET['exclusion_tags'].'\b/u', "", $tags_maior);
```

When I use str_replace or preg_replace like this I get "pac pac pac -carinhoso pac" and I need to get "pac pac pac brasil-carinhoso pac"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All you who vote this down should explain WHY you are voting it down!

Comment: @DanielRibeiro he looks real.

Comment: @cale_b nahhh... **don't wanna**

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables:  I'm with Cale_b, I think you should explain why you are downing voting, because so many people are just to quick with the down vote.  When I don't see any explanation on an even semi decently asked question, I automatically upvote it (without explanation as well :)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I think you've misread that meta link. It doesn't say "don't explain downvotes," not in the slightest. Comments suggesting how a question or answer can be improved are encouraged. In fact, it's right there as [the second bullet](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the page explaining comments, and both linked and quoted in that meta answer. What that meta link is saying is you don't have to (and in fact are encouraged *not* to) **say** you downvoted, as it leads to pointless "noisy" discussions. If you re-read the accepted answer you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm up for 24 hours in this stuff, I'm not even thinking properly, now I see how dumb I was on this question hahaha. Thanks everyone that helped me and everyone that as downvoted me as well hehe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your problem is with your regex. you need to select a word with space before and after the word.

`(space)brazil(space)` is different than just `brazil`

you must now ask the question: "how to do I write a regex that searches for a word that has both a leading and a trailing space?"

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was thinking - exactly 3 seconds before I posted it :)

Comment: What about a dot or any other punctuation mark? e.g.: I like brazil!

Comment: i dont care whether it has that stuff because i'm not trying to solve that problem for him, I'm simply leading him in the right direction by telling him how he should be thinking about this problem..

Comment: @Kristian Nah, not at all, I am well langered tonight, finished a milestone with work, so free to tee up the tots! All power to you for getting in quick :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting you [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) correctly. Your string needs to identify what you want to replace and replace it only if there are spaces before and after your query. I wish I could help more, but I am not well versed in regex. With a little luck, someone will edit this post or provide a regex solution to the query you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$_GET['exclusion_tags'] = 'brazil';
$tags_maior = "pac pac pac brazil brazil-carinhoso pac brazil";
$tags_maior = trim(str_replace(" ".$_GET['exclusion_tags']." ", " ", " ".$tags_maior." "));

var_dump($tags_maior);
```